# svn: E200030: Commit failed

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

When I developed with svnkit 1.8.12 and excuted the svnupload method,sometimes there appears such questions :
svn: E200030: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E200030: Insert fails: unique index sqlite_autoindex_PRISTINE_1.
And my local workingcopy was locked and svn cleanup can unlocked it.I wonder how this question appears and how can I resolve it without changing my local [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJbFj.png)workingcopy.

[svn commit failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJbFj.png)

Answer (score 0):

The goal folder that you wanted to check out from SVN had not been cleaned up because some processes might be using them even though you can delete them. We have experienced this problem for many times in our java program.
At present, what we could do is just restart the tomcat.